# Model Validation not for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a validation in my user model to avoid special char and space in usernames.

By the way I have about 10000 users already registered, some of them with space in the username.

This is my validation

```
 validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/, message: "Non puoi avere spazi o caratteri strani nel tuo username" }
```

How can I add exception for :update, so on update validation are not fired?

Answer (score 2):

If you your validation work for create only, so you can do the following:

```
validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/, message: "Non puoi avere spazi o caratteri strani nel tuo username" }, on: :create
```

Or skip validation if this object isn't new record as:

```
validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/, message: "Non puoi avere spazi o caratteri strani nel tuo username" }, if: :new_record_object?
 def new_record_object?
   self.new_record?
 end
```

Or you can use the following code before save any object:

```
@user.save(validation: false)
```

You can read more about [skipping validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations)

Answer (score 0):

Use `validate: false` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-save

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.username = 'something'
@user.save(validate: false)
```